# Telegram bots: How do you remove a command with botFather

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I am trying to erase all commands from my bot using botFather. I couldn't find docs for this. There is an option to send a new list of commands to the BotFather, however this does not help me as my bot doesn't have any commands as I am working with the custom keyboard.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just add a new list of commands with /setcommands.

your old list will be overwritten.

Comment: I accepted the answer although I couldn't erase all commands as mentioned

Comment: @Guy then just use /empty

Answer (score 4):

There is no direct functionality like "Delete command". You just have to Overide commands again. It like this. Lets assume you have command set like below

- **/love** - Love is eternal
- **/partner** - return partner
- **/status** - return relationship status

Let say you need to remove command **/status** from your bot. First you need to go to **@BotFather** get your list of bots using **/mybots** select your bot, then select **Edit bot** next **Edit Commands**. Now you will prompt to add new set of commands. Then Give command list without the one you need to remove. Like below

**love** - Love is eternal 
**partner** - return partner

Then **BotFather** will add new command set in to you new bot. Don't worry if you can't see your new Command set at once. They will add after like 10 mins

Answer (score 3):

As on today, you can send command /empty to delete all the commands in Edit Commands menu.

Answer (score 0):

BotFather just maintains a list of commands you provide.

You can do a new /setcommands with it, but you can't actually alter the functionality of your bot from there.

Comment: So if I added a command which is no longer need. Is there something I can do?

Comment: But I don't want the bot to have any commands. I am working with the custom keyboard.

Comment: Hmm, I thought I had blanked my commands list before, but I can't find a way to do it now. Perhaps this is a Telegram limitation, but I'll try and see if there is a way around it. For now, I'd suggest just making a command that explains there are no commands.